# Как сделать DropDown Menu в Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать выпадающее меню в Blazor

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/web-development/convert-the-standard-blazor-navigation-menu-to-a-collapsible/m-p/3753268 ссылка на меню show/hide

Answer (score 1):

Можешь использовать библиотеку MudBlazor: https://mudblazor.com/components/menu#simple-menu, пример:

```
    <MudMenu Label="Open Menu">
        <MudMenuItem>Enlist</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Barracks</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Armory</MudMenuItem>
    </MudMenu>
    
    <MudMenu Label="Open Dense Menu" Dense="true">
        <MudMenuItem>Dense Stuff</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Stuff is Dense</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Soo Dense</MudMenuItem>
    </MudMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предложу несколько вариантов.

**1-ый Вариант** (Кастомизированный выпадающий список)

Можно сделать выпадающий список по [наведению](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) или по [нажатию](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp). Также на этом сайте есть ещё варианты оформления такой кнопки.

**2-ой Вариант**

Использование [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

**3-ий Вариант** (Стандартный выпадающий список html. Взято [отсюда](https://blazor-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/49947790/blazor-onchange-event-with-select-dropdown))

```
<select onchange=@DoStuff>
    @foreach (var template in templates)
    {
        <option value=@template>@template</option>
    }
</select>

@functions {
    List<string> templates = new List<string>() { "Maui", "Hawaii", "Niihau", "Kauai", "Kahoolawe" };
    string selectedString = "Maui";

    void DoStuff(UIChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("It is definitely: " + selectedString);
    }
}
```